# @Result at class level and method level

Tags: java, struts2, annotations, struts-action, struts2-convention-plugin

I'm following the [**Struts 2 Hello World Annotation Example**](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-hello-world-annotation-example/) tutorial by Mkyong:

```
@Namespace("/User")
@ResultPath(value="/")
@Action(value="/welcome", 
      results={@Result(name="success", location="pages/welcome_user.jsp")})
public class WelcomeUserAction extends ActionSupport {

    public String execute(){
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Accessing the URL `http://localhost:8080/project_name/User/welcome` works fine.

Now I'm trying to move the @Action (and hence @Result) annotation from class level to method level:

```
@Namespace("/User")
@ResultPath(value="/")
public class WelcomeUserAction extends ActionSupport {

    @Action(value="/welcome", 
          results={@Result(name="success", location="pages/welcome_user.jsp")})     
    public String execute(){
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

But after doing this, I get the 404 error:

> `/project_name/pages/welcome_user.jsp` is not found.

My JSPs are under

> ```
> /WebContent/User/pages
> ```

Why is this happening ?

Comment: What is set for `struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames` in your configuration? Just remove leading slash from action name and it will work -> `@Action(value="welcome"`.

Comment: Answer the question with this other solution @AleksandrM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Struts2 will look for your JSPs in

> ```
> WebContent/@ResultPath/@Namespace/@Result
> ```

Instead of doing

> ```
> @ResultPath("/")/@Namespace("/User")/@Result("pages/welcome_user.jsp")
> ```

you could move your JSPs from

```
WebContent/User/pages/welcome_user.jsp
```

to

```
WebContent/pages/User/welcome_user.jsp
```

and then using

> ```
> @ResultPath("/pages")/@Namespace("/User")/@Result("welcome_user.jsp")
> ```

At this point, both the following configurations should work:

With `@Action` at **class level**:

```
@ResultPath(value="/pages")
@Namespace("/User")
@Action(value="/welcome", results={@Result(name="success", location="welcome_user.jsp")})
public class WelcomeUserAction extends ActionSupport {

    public String execute(){
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

With `@Action` at **method level**:

```
@ResultPath(value="/pages")
@Namespace("/User")
public class WelcomeUserAction extends ActionSupport {

    @Action(value="/welcome", results={@Result(name="success", location="welcome_user.jsp")})
    public String execute(){
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

I don't know why Mkyong's example works only with annotations at class level, and I'm waiting for someone more expert to fullfil our curiosity; meanwhile, this should be what you need.

Comment: Thank you Andrea Ligios!